# How to bind a multiple specific value from json file in Angular?

Tags: angular, function, binding, components

I'm trying to do a simple @input binding process in Angular. I did most of it. I don't know why but i can't get the data. I think my .map usage has a problem.

This is my parent component.ts

```
export class DashboardContainerComponent implements OnInit {   cards: { title: string, body: string }[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").subscribe((comments: any) => {
      cts
      // this.cards = comments. ... map? reduce? filter?
      this.cards = comments.map(n => {
        return {title: n["name"], body: n["body"] };
      } )  
    })   }

}
```

This is child component.ts

```
export class MyCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() item: {title: string, body: string}[];
  // TODO: define @Input(s) here
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

This is how i use this binding in my parent component.html

```
<div class="dashboard-container">
  <h1>Comments</h1>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!cards">
    <div class="info-text">Cards will appear here.</div> 
  </ng-container>
  
  <ng-container *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <!-- TODO: assign input(s) below in app-my-card -->
    <app-my-card [item]="cards"></app-my-card>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

And this is how i use this binding in my child component.html

```
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card-title">
    <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p>{{item.body}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an inconsistency in your child component, between template and TS files regarding what is "item"
Your child component should either take in an item, or an array of items but not both :

- Calling the child template you pass [item]="cards", so the full array
- In the child .ts file item is declared as an array
- In the child template file item is expected to be an object with .title & .body, yet it has an array (so undefined).

Here is what seems to make sense :
type the input as a single element

```
@Input() item: {title: string, body: string}; // <= no more array
```

...and pass it the element defined in the *ngFor (instead of the full array)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <!-- TODO: assign input(s) below in app-my-card -->
    <app-my-card 
        [item]="card" // NOT cards 
    ></app-my-card>
  </ng-container>
```

Do NOT hesitate to understand what is happening by adding for debug something like this in your child template

```
<pre>item : {{ item | json }} </pre>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally missed that cards/card situation. It fixed my problem.